# How to denote an equal frequency of common subsequences in two sequences?

Tags: sequences-and-series, notation, inclusion-exclusion

What would be the most appropriate symbol for denoting an equal number of subsequences in two sequences? For example:

$$A = (1,2,3,4),\ B=(9,2,3,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4),\ C = (9,1,2,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,7).$$

Let $\preceq$ denote a proper subsequence. $A\preceq B$ and $A\preceq C$. Further, $A$ occurs at least as frequently in sequence $B$ as in sequence $C$. Is there a logical symbol to denote this?

Comment: I guess you have to make up your own

Comment: Yes, since I am new to this I want to make sure to choose a symbol that is at least used for something close or won't easily be confused for something else